# popup (like sap.m.dialog) with multiple windows

Tags: javascript, popup, sapui5, multi-window

I´m planning to create a popup window, which has multiple views/screens/or something like that where you can navigate through. I want to keep it responsive so my initial thought was using sap.m.dialog. I´m also using only XML views/fragments and I want to keep it stringent.
I looked at the test ressources and found something pretty usefull for sap.ui.commons.Dialog - [Dialog - SAPUI5 Demo Kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Dialog.html)

Even though the idea is good, it doesn´t seem to work with sap.m.Dialog (especially the last example with XML fragments).

Does anyone of you know how to create a responsive popup with different screens (maybe a fragment for each view) where you can navigate through?

My approaches so far do not look very promissing, but I could also post some code if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is bad that nobody might help, thus I'll try my best. As far as I get you, you are trying to open a Dialog with some navigation possiblity and it should be responsible. My idea on this would be do use a commons.Dialog in combination with Roadmap (sap.ui.commons.RoadMap) -> the Thing with Roadmaps is, that depending on the selected Roadmap-step you can open different views (each view will Show in the size you want it to be) .. not ultimatively responsible, but it is an idea. might this help?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is indeed a interesting approach. What I did so far is to create a Dialog in xml view and add different fragments to it. You can navigate through these fragments by its IDs.
This might be the easiest solution - my first approach was way too complicated, that´s why I created this question.

Anyway, thanks again for your help, never heard of UI5 RoadMap before but it might be helpful in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

While its possible to add a nav controller (sap.m.App) into a dialog , I have never tried it out though. The page width is automatically adjusted via dialog size. I think you can try with multiple navigation using a simple fragment that loads an app and root view. Further navigation can be handled by the controller that presents the dialog. I havent tried this out yet but I am sure this will work. I will do a little more research and put up some code for you.